# CDI. Using @Specializes

Tags: java, cdi

I have a question about using `@Specialization`. As prescribed by the Java EE 6 or 7 tutorials if I declare my bean by giving it `@Specializes` annotation that it ' ll completely replace bean, which extends my bean. E.g.

```
    public interface I {}
    @Default @Q
    public class A implements I {}
    @Specializes
    public class SpecA extends A {}
    ////
    a) @Inject I a;
    b) @Inject @Q I b;
```

Is it enough for that SpecA will be injected to fields 'a' and 'b'?
I tried to run this example on glassfish 4.0 and it didn't worked.

I have read strange sentences in tutorials:
'Usually, a bean marked with the `@Specializes` annotation is also an alternative and is declared as an alternative in the `beans.xml` file. '
I don't understand what should I do to do make it work as prescribed in tutorials? Do I need add annotation `@Alternative` and add this class to `beans.xml`? Or Do I need add my bean to `beans.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions

> Do I need add annotation `@Alternative` and add this class to beans.xml?

Yes

> Do I need add my bean to beans.xml?

No. Above will do

Giving you more context :

`@Specializes` is more or less meant to specialize an `@Alternative` bean.

`@Specializes` comes handy when the `@Alternative` bean is meant to replace

- a bean/implementation that is annotated with one or more qualifiers
  and
- the injection points are using the one/more qualifiers.

Case 1 : You have one bean/implementation (lets call `BeanA`) with no qualifiers. In this case you don't need `@Specializes`, you will have to

1. Create a `@Alternative` bean (let's call AltBean) that you want to use
   as a replacement for BeanA
2. List `AltBean` in beans.xml as alternative

Case 2 : You have one bean/implementation (in your case A) with one or more qualifiers. In this case you have to

1. Create a `@Alternative` **and** `@Specializes` bean (`SpecA`)
   that you want to use as a replacement for A
2. Make `SpecA` extend `A`
3. List `SpecA` in beans.xml as alternative

Yours is Case 2.